# How to merge two queries into one without using case when in SQL?

Tags: sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions, amazon-athena

I have two queries that I would like to put together:

Query 1

```
SELECT 
   SUM(sales) AS sales,
   SUM(profit) AS profit
FROM X
WHERE site = 'de'
```

Query 2

```
SELECT 
    SUM(sales) AS sales_flag,
    SUM(profit) AS profit_flag
FROM X
WHERE site = 'de'
  AND flag = true
```

I would like to have an output something like this:

```
sales | sales_flag | profit | profit_flag
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use conditional sums in same query, like `sum(case when flag = true then sales else 0 end) as sales_flag`.

Comment: Arvo is right with his suggestion. But as for you question: you use a UNION when you want to combine two queries' results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(sales) as sales,
    sum(case when flag = true then sales end) as sales_flag,
    sum(profit) as profit,
    sum(case when profit = true then sales end) as profit_flag
from x
where site = 'de'
```